# Typescript type T or function () => T usage

Tags: typescript

You can see a demo in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgS2AghgGwQLwgJwDwAqAfFALxQFQA+UAFLQJRkkEMBQbAZgK5wDGyAPZwofQThwQBtFDgDmALliJk6LLjwBnYDgRw5RJgG82UM1EnBuOEaEiDOUWXLKlyAch78hcd1AD8TvKMUErObAC+HF4CCMJQAO44wnKERDLySvBIqBjY+MTGpuaW1rbgEA5BLm4eMT5+gc4hYfKRHGJw2lAImgBivLHx5BmKTnAgDK0uvVAD3nEipCR2lY7OrnWDDdHbi6LikgIA+gBMaaNZKrnqBYZQJuYWEFY2Pf17wqNMTcFM05EgA).

I've made a simple generic type which can represent either a variable or a function that returns a variable. But, unfortunately, it doesn't work with a typical `typeof arg === 'function'` check. It produces the following error:

`This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type '(() => T) | (T & Function)' are callable.
    Type 'T & Function' has no call signatures.`

Is there a way to make it work without using type guard function?

```js
type Initializer<T> = T | (() => T)

function correct(arg: Initializer<string>) {
    return typeof arg === 'function' ? arg() : arg
}

function wrong<T>(arg: Initializer<T>) {
    return typeof arg === 'function' ? arg() : arg // error here
}

const isFunction = (arg: any): arg is Function => typeof arg === 'function'

function correct_2<T>(arg: Initializer<T>) {
    return isFunction(arg) ? arg() : arg
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write:

```
type Initializer<T> = T extends any ? (T | (() => T)) : never

function correct<T>(arg: Initializer<T>): T {
    return typeof arg === 'function' ? arg() : arg // works
    // arg is Initializer<T> & Function in the true branch
}

const r1 = correct(2) // const r1: 2
const r2 = correct(() => 2) // const r2: number
```

In the original version, `arg` is resolved to `(() => T) | (T & Function)` in the true branch. TS apparently can't recognize for this union function type, that both constituents *are* callable. At least in above version, it is clear for the compiler that you can invoke `arg` after a function check.

Might also be worth to [create a github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript) for this case in the TypeScript repository - in my opinion `T & Function` *should* represent some (wide) type of function.

Comment: That's a smart trick, thanks. I've created an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37663).

Comment: Heh, that GitHub issue says that this trick is the bug, and that the original behavior is correct (that part makes sense since if `T` is itself a function type like `(x: string) => number`, then it is not safe to call `arg()`.

Comment: The issue also [says](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37663#issuecomment-759728342) working with `instanceof Function` is a good workaround

Answer (score 5):

Using `instanceof Function` to check if `arg` is callable works nicely:

```js
type Initializer<T> = T | (() => T)

function fixed<T>(arg: Initializer<T>) {
  // Instead of using `typeof`:
  // return typeof arg === 'function' ? arg() : arg // error here

  // use `instanceof`
  return arg instanceof Function ? arg() : arg
}
```

This was originally described by [kentcdodds on a GitHub issue related to this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37663#issuecomment-759728342).

Answer (score 4):

I tried a different approach than that in accepted answer, by forbidding T (expected resolved value) to be a function. It seems to work in most use cases, unless you are trying to produce functions from the initializer.

```
type Initializer<T> = T extends Function ? never : T | (() => T);

function foo<T>(r: Initializer<T>): T {
  return typeof r === 'function' ? r() : r;
}


const valOK = foo('2');
const funOK = foo(() => 4);

const funError = foo((a: number, b: number) => a + b);  // Expected error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=55&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgOwJYiQQwDZIF5QE4A8AKgHwwC8MRMUAHiFAgCYDOMAYgK4IDGqA9ghgB%20GAigA3fDABcVGAB8YACmUBKCmSJqA3MGAAzbnySCYB-v2IlleOYhTosuQqTVzqAb2AwYeKCCceELg0PwGfhTklADkRrwCCDEifuqyfnoAvvrAPIIsIDASmADyANIU5pbKMQBMMbq5%20YXx5ZUW-Koa5GQALI1NCAXm3ACieHj8eO3VymhyCJwAtgBG%20AA0MCsLy2t43WRoMADUW7pAA)