# How to differentiate between value and callback argument type

Tags: typescript, callback, overloading

This snippet

```
function problem<T>(callback: T | (() => T)) : T {
    return typeof callback === 'function' ? callback() : callback;
}
```

produces the error

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type '(() => T) | (T & Function)' are callable.
    Type 'T & Function' has no call signatures. ts(2349)
```

It took me a while to understand that `Function` itself indeed doesn't mean much, since I need is a *parameter-less* function.

In special cases like `T = number`, I can simple switch to testing `typeof callback === 'number'` and be done. However, I need a general solution.

I'd like to

- either restrict `T` so that it does not include functions, which (as I hope) solves the problem.
- or do a runtime test for parameterless function

I'm also open for alternatives (my main point is to learn about the details).

What are the possibilities?

#### Problem explanation

With `function myfun(s: string) {return s;}` and the call

```
problem(myfun);
```

the type `T = (s: string) => string` gets correctly inferred. There should be no callback call like `myfun()`; instead, `myfun` should be returned. However, it goes wrong as `typeof callback === 'function'` holds.

#### Update

I was wrong assuming that <strike>Checking `callback instanceof Function` is AFAIK exactly the same.</strike>

It's different, as the [playground from the answer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE5wEYBsCmBbAHgBUA+ACggEMssNKIBrALkSMQB9EyyBKRAXhKsePFmwDeAKESJUOKCFRIqNOo0QwwAZyiVIOOMEQAxcNHhIA-IhW16DXoha21DANySAvpMkQEOm2o7RgAleUVtAGUoVE0AcwEuPkFEAHIACRwaOAAaRAB1OFQsABNEYHQ8crNYBABCVI8-bShEACsQHQBBaNiwBP40zOy8wuKyirgq5p09KAafGbhcADosODiyNExcPAog1zCFJS1e+JEm-2WcNY2t9Gx8Mg7us-6LySA) shows. However, adding

```
const myfun = (s: string) => s;
console.log(problem(myfun));
```

makes it say

```
Argument of type '(s: string) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | (() => string)'.
  Type '(s: string) => string' is not assignable to type '() => string'.ts(2345)
doAfter.ts(57, 21): Did you mean to call this expression?
```

This sounds like a bug as this line

```
console.log(problem<(s: string) => string>(myfun));
```

compiles and there's no type ambiguity. However, it doesn't work, `undefined` gets returned instead of `myfun` itself.

#### The potential duplicate

The answer of the linked question doesn't solve my problem either:

- Plain `correct(myfun);` does not compile.
- Valid `correct<(s: string) => string>(myfun)` return undefined.

My second question "(how to) do a runtime test for parameterless function" is absent from the potential duplicate, too.

Comment: If you're happy with that behaviour at runtime, you can use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) to explain as much to the compiler: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgMXNeYA8AVAPgAoIBDAG3ICNSIBrALkT0QB9EiiBKRAXgOZcuTMpRr1kKDtz4C8PAN4BYAFCJ1iAE4BTKCE1IoATwAO2uMESjqtOn169EAclCRYCJwG5VAX1WrXLAREE004KnJtAFt8YmtxRmY2aR5+QWEk5TUNHT0DSQw3bBIKG3oeAH4rUoSZERrbbxU-FSA

Comment: How about using `callback instanceof Function ? callback() : callback` instead?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's not the problem: Typescript *does* understand that `callback` is a function. However, it says that it lacks call signatures and it is right: See my edit.

Comment: @CRice I'd bet, nothing changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript type T or function () => T usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898079/typescript-type-t-or-function-t-usage)

Comment: I don't think the edit added a great deal of clarification. The problem is that the compiler doesn't know that `T` is intended to exclude functions, so `typeof callback === "function"` doesn't actually narrow to `() => T`, and that it can't work out that the resulting union is all callable. The suggestion of the predicate is to inform the compiler to make that narrowing, but again that's on the assumption that the *runtime behaviour* of the code you show is what you want.

Comment: "Checking `callback instanceof Function` is *AFAIK* the same"? "*I'd bet*, nothing changes"? What is this? Did you try it or not, why the ambiguity?

Comment: @CRice I did try it just now.... see my update. To my big surprise, it behaves differently, but as expected, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm considering voting for closing my question, but I'm still unsure.

Comment: There's not a lot we can do with "unsure", I'm afraid. If you try that answer and it doesn't solve your problem, [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Now, I did.... however, my question needs a full rewrite as it's more of a conversation now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do now.

Goal: If the given callback is not parameter-less, then it should be inferred as the `T` type and returned directly. If it is parameter-less, it should be inferred as `() => T` and invoked. To do that I would recommend using an [overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) like so:

```
function problem<T extends () => any>(callback: T): ReturnType<T>;
function problem<T>(callback: T): T;
function problem(callback: unknown): unknown {
    /* ... */
}
```

Then, when using it the following types are inferred:

```
const test0 = problem("") // literal type: ""
const test1 = problem(() => "") // string
const test2 = problem((s: string) => s) // (s: string) => string
```

Finally, you'll need to change the check in `problem`'s implementation so that it can determine if the given callback is a function and if it accepts parameters or not. Thankfully in javascript, functions have a `.length` property, indicating the number of required arguments (with caveats for variadic functions and default parameters). So:

```
return callback instanceof Function && !callback.length ? callback() : callback;
```

should work.

---

[Playground Link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQAcBOSBGAbAUwFsAeAFVQIA84CoATAZ1QAoBKVAXgD5UBDKAE9uLGHzx4cfGAGsAXKjJsFAJQJwImKGUHoC5bgG5QkWIhQZs+YgdHjJ0+YuWLj4aPGRosuQkTsSUrIK0DJQSADuUC6h4VGoAN6gqCmomOqaaGKBjqgIUIxwAjAESGCoAGIe5mgAZLWoAITZDrIAdIRQAOZwABaoAPyoLUEy7KgKI45uAL6goDAohai0hQAMXJa+xCwARLscAPSHqIWY+V0LS3ArBIUAjJs+1v7jPKj7RydnF1cFN6s4AAmJ5WPwsFiMBQ-bocd6ML6sKGnODnWFcXgwy4gIA)

Comment: Perfect! While I no more believe that such a function is a good idea, but what I learnt is surely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Checking via `instanceof` should be enough:

```
function problem<T>(callback: T | ((...args: any[]) => T)): T {
  return callback instanceof Function ? callback() : callback;
}

const functionReturnsFromParameter = (s: string) => s;
const callbackReturnsString = () => 'Hello, World from function!';
const justAString = 'Hello, World from constant!'

console.log(problem(functionReturnsFromParameter))
console.log(problem(callbackReturnsString));
console.log(problem(justAString));
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE5wEYBsCmBbAHgBUA+ACggEMssNKIBrALkSMQB9EyyA6Py1AHMAzi0pgAngG0AugEpEAXhKs5clmwDeAKESJUOKCFRIqNOo0QwwwqOIg44wRADFw0eEgD8iM7XoMZAosfhYMANzaAL7a2hAItoigkLAIAEqGxjYu6HgACgKUeIY4qEpcooi2qNaCCspVkfE2UL7U-owZRibCAMpQNWCC5UFKKgDkABI4NHAANIgA6nCoWAAmSblJ7qlgAITjTQmtAFYgtgCC-YPDiohTM1jzSyvrm3B4vsfiUAexzcI4LgeE9BGQ0JhcHgyMkPOlMj0ch8CqgiiVUGo4gkgTgQXAwRDsPgKO0wl0sn0BrU1EcbDi8QT0EToWdLtdqXJIkA)

Comment: This doesn't compile for `const myfun = (s: string) => s;`. It does, when using type arguments like `problem<(s: string) => string>(myfun)`, but returns a wrong result (namely undefined).

Comment: It returns undefined because you passed a function but did not provided the arguments. Still, it is a function that can be called. It is expected behaviour.

Comment: I've updated the code so it compiles with your `myfun`, but again... You are not calling the function with the string argument, so where from it should take your string then?

Comment: It shouldn't take any string, but rather return the function as is. The reason for the overload is simplifying the usage: you either pass a value itself or a parameterless function providing the value (this means that the value can't be a parameterless function, but that's OK). With `myfun`, it should be treated as a value.

Comment: Why do you trying to call the function then? According to your wording, you just return the value as is in both cases, either it is a function or not, you just return what was passed.

Comment: No.... I want to call it if it's a parameterless function and leave alone everything else. It's probably not worth the hassle, but I found it pretty handy for e.g., a timeout using thing like `function later(valueOrFunction: T | (() => T))`.