# How to determine if a union type is a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Using TypeScript 4.2.2, I have this type:

```
type Resolvable<T> = T | (() => T);
```

In other words, this is either a value of type `T`, or a function that returns a value of type `T`. This can be useful if a value needs to be passed into an object but the value isn't computed yet but needs to be lazily computed when needed.

When a function takes this as an argument, I want to resolve it into a value by checking if it's a function, in which case it's invoked to get the value, otherwise the value is used directly.

Simplified example:

```
function foo<T>(r: Resolvable<T>): T {
  return typeof r === 'function' ? r() : r;
}
```

This is a common pattern in plain JavaScript. However, the TypeScript compiler complains about the function type check, and apparently cannot determine that r is indeed `() => T` and *not* `T` if `typeof r === 'function'`:

```
Error:(10, 36) TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type '(() => T) | (T & Function)' are callable.
    Type 'T & Function' has no call signatures.
```

Am I missing something here, or should the compiler be able to deduce the type from the `typeof r === 'function'` check? What does `T & Function` has no call signatures mean? If an object is a function *and* something else, it should still be callable?

I wondered whether the problem could be that `T` could itself be a function. In that case, `Resolvable<T>` would either be a function, or a function that returns a function. In either case, I'd argue that `if typeof r === 'function'` should suffice to allow invoking `r()`, so it doesn't seem like this would be the issue. Is there any case where something that passes the `typeof === 'function'` test *isn't* callable?

However, I did notice that `function foo<T extends string>` works, but `function foo<T extends Function>` does not, so it does seem like the problem is related to `T` possibly being a function itself, and I guess it could then be that if `T` is, say, a `(a: string, b: number) => number`, then `r()` is indeed not necessarily callable.

I'd hate having to resort to `function foo<T extends string | number | ...>` because honestly, I'd then want `T` to be anything *but* a function rather than having to list all other types.

Comment: "I wondered whether the problem could be that T could itself be a function."  I think that's it.  I am not getting the error with this definition which bars `T` as a function `type Resolvable<T> = T extends Function ? never : T | (() => T);`

Comment: @JHH how about forbidding T (expected resolved value) to be a function? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66465290/1570854

Comment: @LindaPaiste. Yes, I ended up defining a `NotFunction<T>` exactly like that. Thanks.