# "This expression is not callable" in Typescript with type narrowing

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm defining a function with the same signature as React's useState:

```
declare function useState<S>(
  initialState: S | (() => S),
): [S, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<S>>];
```

Here's part of the function:

```
function foo<T>(initialState: T | (() => T)) {
  typeof initialState === 'function' ? initialState() : initialState;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type '(() => T) | (T & Function)' are callable.
    Type 'T & Function' has no call signatures.(2349)
```

Doesn't `T & Function` mean that `T` is a function, so it would be callable? How can I fix this without forced type casts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript type T or function () => T usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898079/typescript-type-t-or-function-t-usage)

Comment: Also, there is an open issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37663

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type can be successfully narrowed using `initialState instanceof Function`:

```js
function foo<T>(initialState: T | (() => T)) {
  initialState instanceof Function ? initialState() : initialState;
}
```

Edit: interestingly, this compiles, but it will fail for some edge cases. For example, if `initialState` is `Object.create(Function.prototype)`. This is an instance of `Function` but is not callable.

Comment: Interesting, `typeof === 'function'` seems safer, I wonder why it's like this

Comment: Wow. What a weird solution. Don't they both accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way would be to tell the complier that `initialState` is a function when `typeof initialState` is `'function'`.

```
function foo<T>(initialState: T | (() => T)) {
  if (isFunction(initialState)) {
    initialState();
  } else {
    initialState;
  }
}

function isFunction<T>(f: T | (() => T)): f is (() => T) {
  return typeof f === 'function';
}
```

Comment: Does not work. Only `instanceof Function` seems to work

Comment: How doesn't it work? It seems it's working on the Playground. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfAChmGWAQwBsBlKIqAUwC5ENEAfRHHASkQF4sH3OA3gChEiGMFYwAzgDFw0eGDwFi5SjX6Jho0fkIxSFKtQ4BuEYgC+iaiSnUtF3SoNrj50ZaFehoSLAQxWXkAsExcYHpGFjZOHj52eglpVg5uXgxBCwAnaigQbKQoAE8AB2o4CQkuGsQAcj8FBDrzHxQ4HABGdnN22PTEbvMgA