# Write generic function accepting either function or non-function argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have some variables that can contain either a (static) non-function value or a function that will generate the value (dynamically).

```
type StaticOrDynamic<T> = T | () => T;
```

This signature doesn't actually guarantee that `T` is not a function, but as long as I declare the type parameter's value everything works fine:

```
const x: StaticOrDynamic<string> = "foo";
console.log(typeof x === "function" ? x() : x); // prints "foo"

const y: StaticOrDynamic<string> = () => "bar";
console.log(typeof x === "function" ? x() : x); // prints "bar"
```

Now I want to write a generic function to "unwrap" any possible `StaticOrDynamic` value, but I get a compilation error:

```
function unwrap<T>(value: StaticOrDynamic<T>): T {
  if (typeof value === "function")
    return value(); // Error here: value could be of type (T & Function)
  else
    return value;
}
```

I understand this is due to the fact that nowhere I'm telling the compiler that `T` is not a function type.

How can I write such a function?

Comment: Looks like there are a few workarounds for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898079/typescript-type-t-or-function-t-usage); potential duplicate?

Comment: sure, it is a duplicate thank you. I could not find it because of the title. Not easy to find the correct wording...